# my whole website pushed to the left in responsive mode how to find the problem?

Tags: javascript, html, css

my whole website pushes content to left and usually its due to syntax error but i really cant find my problem please help I'm a beginner and my code has a lot of noise and i have run the html and css in multiple formatter and validator websites and still did not find anything i also removed all media queries to se if the problem resolved but no luck please help me.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: visible;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


body {
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

/*Button Back To Top-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#myBtn {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Fixed/sticky position */
  bottom: 20px; /* Place the button at the bottom of the page */
  right: 30px; /* Place the button 30px from the right */
  z-index: 99; /* Make sure it does not overlap */
  border: none; /* Remove borders */
  outline: none; /* Remove outline */
  background-color: #f10e32; /* Set a background color */
  color: white; /* Text color */
  cursor: pointer; /* Add a mouse pointer on hover */
  padding: 15px; /* Some padding */
  border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners */
  font-size: 18px; /* Increase font size */
}
#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #d19ea6;
}
/*NAVBAR --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.navbar {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #18191a;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}
.mylist {
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.icons {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.icons a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(180, 148, 158);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.icons:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.icon {
  width: 35px;
  height: auto;
}
/*INFO -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.head-info {
  background-color: rgba(134, 128, 128, 0.035);
  width: 70%;
  border-radius: 10px;

}

.info {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.info p {
  color: rgb(218, 214, 214);
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 5px 150px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

h1 {
  color: rgb(177, 164, 164);
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
h2 {
  color: rgb(192, 184, 153);
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: crimson;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.btn {
  margin: 80px 0 0 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: #f10e32;
  border: none;
  width: 136px;
  height: auto;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: rgb(198, 181, 181);
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*PROJECTS---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.projects {
 
  scroll-behavior: smooth;

  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(134, 128, 128, 0.035);
  border-radius: 10px;

}
.projects h4 {
  display: none;
}
.one,
.two,
.three {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  position: relative;
}
.images {
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 320px;
  height: 220px;

  border-radius: 4px;
}

h5 {
  position: relative;
  right: 200px;
  top: 5px;
}
.image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h5 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#first,
#second,
#third,
#fourth,
#fifth,
#sixth,
#seventh
 {
  position: relative;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.705);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.overlay p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #daced0;
}
.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

/*Summery and Skills -------------------------------------------------------------*/
.about {
  background-color: rgba(134, 128, 128, 0.035);

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;

  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  padding: 70px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.about h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.about p {
  color: rgb(218, 214, 214);
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 5px 150px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.skills {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.skill {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.skill a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(180, 148, 158);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.skill a:hover {
  transform: translateY(-20px);

}

/*CONTACTS ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.contact {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.096);
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  
 text-align: center; 
 
}
.contacts h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#centrada{
  margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
  width:300px;
  font-family: 'Verdana';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.utopix{
  padding-bottom:50px;
}
a{
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 250ms ease;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.default-state,.active-state {
  height: 50px;
}
.cube +.cube{
margin:10px 0px;
}
.default-state {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(25px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(25px);
  -o-transform: translateZ(25px);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(25px);
  transform: translateZ(25px);
}
.flip-to-top .active-state {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  -o-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(75px);
}
.flip-to-bottom .active-state {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
  -o-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
}
.cube.flip-to-top:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-89deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-89deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(-89deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-89deg);
  transform: rotateX(-89deg);
}
.cube.flip-to-bottom:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(89deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(89deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(89deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(89deg);
  transform: rotateX(89deg);
}
.cube {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.default-state,
.active-state {
  font-size: 16px;
  
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: background 250ms ease;
  -moz-transition: background 250ms ease;
  -o-transition: background 250ms ease;
  transition: background 250ms ease;
}
.cube:hover .default-state {
  background: #000;
}
.facebook {
  background: #016d1f;
}
.twitter {
  background: #0ec90b;
}
.google-plus {
  background: #c01a04;
}
.linkedin {
  background:#0590db;
}
.instagram {
  background-color: #da4273;
}

/*MEDIA ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/css/all.css">


       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">       <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
       <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

       <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
       <div class="container">
              <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

             
              <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
                     
                     <ul class="mylist" >
                            
                            <li class="icons" title="HOME">
                                   <a href="./index.html"><img class="icon" src="./images/home.png" alt="">
                                          Home
                                   </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="icons" title="resume">
                                   <a href="download=""><img class="icon" src="./images/Resume.png"  alt="">
                                          Get Resume
                                          
                                   </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="icons" title="ABOUT ME">
                                   <a href="#about"><img  class="icon" src="./images/about.png" alt="Todo List">
                                          About
                                   </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="icons" title="CONTACT ME">
                                   <a href="#contacts"><img class="icon" src="./images/contact-book.png"  alt="">
                                          Contacts
                                   </a>
                            </li>
                            
                     </ul>
              </nav>

              <div class="info">
                     <div class="head-info">
                     <h1></h1>
                     <h2>Front-End Developer</h2>
                     <h3>Objective</h3>
                     <p>As a Front-End Developer, to be responsible for producing high quality solutions for company customers; bringing growing understanding of Modern HTML, JavaScript, and CSS, and passionate ability to learn and develope while working in the team of experts under a skillful and talented management.
                     </div>
                   <a class="btn" href="#first">VIEW PROJECTS</a>
              </div>

       <div id="projects" class="projects">
              <div id="first-div" class="one">
                     <div id="first" class="image-container">
                           <a href="./projects/color-flipper/index.html" target="_blank">
                            

                            <img src="./images/projects/Color-flipper.png" class="images" alt="Color Flipper">
                            <div class="overlay"><p>Color Flipper</p></div>
                            <h4>Color Flipper</h4>
                            </a>
                     </div>
                     
                     
                     <div id="second" class="image-container">
                            <a href="./projects/Comment/index.html"  target="_blank">
                                   <img src="./images/projects/secrets.png" class="images" alt="Secrets">
                                   <div class="overlay"><p>Secrets</p></div>
                                   <h4>Secrets</h4>
                            </a>
                     </div>
                            

                            <div id="third" class="image-container">
                                   <a href="./projects/counter/index.html"  target="_blank"
                                   ><img src="./images/projects/counter.png" class="images" alt="Counter">
                                   <div class="overlay"><p>Counter</p></div>
                                   <h4>Counter</h4>
                            </a>
                                   
                            </div>
                                   
              </div>
              <div  class="two">
                     
                    

                     <div id="fourth" class="image-container">
                            <a href="./projects/Login-page/index.html"  target="_blank">
                                   <img src="./images/projects/login.png" class="images" alt="Login">
                                   <div class="overlay"><p>Login Page</p></div>
                                   <h4>Login-Page</h4>
                            </a>
                            
                     </div>
                            

                            
                                   
              </div>
              <div class="three">
                     <div  id="fifth" class="image-container">
                            <a href="./projects/Random Quotes/index.html"  target="_blank">
                                   <img src="./images/projects/quotes.png" class="images" alt="Quotes">
                                   <div class="overlay"><p>Random Quotes</p></div>
                                   <h4>Random Quotes</h4>
                            </a>
                           
                     </div>
                    

                     <div id="sixth" class="image-container">
                            <a href="./projects/responsive-header/index.html"  target="_blank">
                                   <img src="./images/projects/header.png" class="images" alt="Movies">
                                   <div class="overlay"><p>Movies</p></div>
                                   <h4>Movies</h4>
                            </a>
                            
                     </div>
                            
                            <div id="seventh" class="image-container">
                                   <a href="./projects/todo-list/index.html"  target="_blank">
                                          <img src="./images/projects/todo.png" class="images" alt="">
                                          <div class="overlay"><p>Todo List</p></div>
                                          <h4>Todo-List</h4>
                                   </a>
                                   
                            </div>
                                  
              </div>
       </div>





              <div id="about" class="about">
                     <h3>Summery</h3>
                     <p>With over 5 years of experience in English translation I have decided to change my career into something more rewarding and futureproof such as web development.
                            So as of 2019 I have trained online to become a front-end web developer and covered various topics such as responsive web design, vanilla JavaScript web application basics and user friendly UI and UX design. 
                     </p>


                     <div class="skills">
                            <h3>Skills</h3>

                            <div class="skill">

                                   <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#:~:text=The%20HyperText%20Markup%20Language%2C%20or,scripting%20languages%20such%20as%20JavaScript."><img src="./images/skills/html.png" alt=""><br>HTML</a>
                                   <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS"><img src="./images/skills/css.png" alt=""><br>CSS3</a>
                                   <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript"><img src="./images/skills/js.png" alt=""><br>JAVASCRIPT</a>
                                   <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git"><img src="./images/skills/git.png" alt=""><br>Git</a>
                                   <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figma_(software)"><img src="./images/skills/figma.png" alt=""><br>Figma</a>
                                   <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress"><img src="./images/skills/wordpress.png" alt=""><br>Wordpress</a>
                                   <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop"><img src="./images/skills/photoshop.png" alt=""><br>Photoshop</a>
                                   <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word"><img src="./images/skills/word.png" alt=""><br>Word</a>
                                   <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel"><img src="./images/skills/excel.png" alt=""><br>Excell</a>
                                   <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_PowerPoint"><img src="./images/skills/powerpoint.png" alt=""><br>Powerpoint</a>
                            </div>
                            
                     </div>
                     
              </div>


          

       
             <div id="contacts" class="contacts">

              <h3>Contact Me</h3>

              <div id="centrada">

                       
                     <div class="cube flip-to-top">
                              <div class="default-state facebook">
                                       <span>Phone</span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="active-state facebook">
                                       <span><a  href="tel:123-456-7890" target="_blank">+98-0990-136-91-46</a></span>
                              </div>
                     </div>
                     
                     <div class="cube flip-to-top google-plus">
                              <div class="default-state">
                                       <span>Gmail</span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="active-state google-plus">
                                       <span><a>naeimipoor.a@gmail.com</a></span>
                              </div>
                     </div>
                     
                     
                     <div class="cube flip-to-top twitter">
                              <div class="default-state">
                                       <span>Whatsapp</span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="active-state twitter">
                                       <span><a href="https://wa.me/+9809901369146">+98-990-136-91-46</a></span>
                              </div>
                     </div>
                     
                     <div class="cube flip-to-top">
                              <div class="default-state linkedin">
                                       <span>Linkedin</span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="active-state linkedin">
                                       <span><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ashkan-naeimipoor-7b655316a" target="_blank">Ashkan Naeimipoor</a></span>
                              </div>
                     </div>
                       
                   
                     </div>

             </div>





              
             
           
       </div>
       

















       <script>
              /*NAVBAR JAVASCRIPT-----------------------------------------*/
              var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}

/*BACK ON TOP BUTTON JAVASCRIPT------------------------------------------------*/
//Get the button:
mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
}
       </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `background-size` is well supported by all browsers. It does not need any `vendor-prefix`. The issue itself is cause because you have no `media queries` to handle your breakpoints caused by the use of fixed width in pixel

Comment: i just noticed that the problem only shows on chrome and not Firefox is there something wrong with chrome dev tools and if so is there any other more accurate way of checking website responsiveness?

Comment: Running your snippet, on my Chorme (WIndows10) Responsive mode in the dev tools keeps everything centered.

Answer (score 2):

Add `flex-wrap:wrap` on `.skill`

```
.skill {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /*Add Here*/
}
```